# ActiveJob cannot schedule jobs in the future, although Sidekiq is set as queue adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have an `ActiveJob` job which I would like to run sometime in the future. I'm using [this template](https://github.com/mattbrictson/rails-template) with Sidekiq integrated. Sidekiq web UI is up and running, Redis is setup, etc. The app starts up fine.

I'm trying to schedule inside `application.rb`, so maybe this is where it's going wrong. The code is:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  ...
  SomeJob.new.enqueue(wait: 10.seconds)
end
```

The error and stacktrace are:

> Uncaught exception: Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the
>   future. Read more at
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/inline_adapter.rb:18:in
>   `enqueue_at'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:69:in`
>   block in enqueue'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in
>   `call'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in`
>   block (2 levels) in compile'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in
>   `call'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in`
>   block (2 levels) in around'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in
>   `block (2 levels) in simple'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in
>   `block in tag_logger'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`
>   block in tagged'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`
>   tagged'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in
>   `tag_logger'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in
>   `instance_exec'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in`
>   block in make_lambda'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in
>   `block in simple'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in`
>   block in around'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in
>   `call'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`
>   **run_callbacks**'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in
>   `_run_enqueue_callbacks'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in
>   `enqueue'
>     /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in`
>   perform_later'

If anybody has any hints, that would be great.

Comment: Put the perform_async at the bottom of your sidekiq.rb initializer.

Comment: @Mike: OK, so that's where you usually put the jobs initialization code. Will try it soon, thanks!